# Unable to serialize model with Highcharts property

Tags: c#, serialization, highcharts

Firstly apology for my English, as I'm not the best at explaining things, but here goes

Using MVC I have the following model

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
      .
      .
      .
      [DataMember]
      public Dictionary<string, Highcharts> MyProperty{ get; set; } 
 }
```

When I come to serialize the model using

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
                string xmlString;

                using (var sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                        serializer.WriteObject(writer, model);
                        writer.Flush();
                        xmlString = sw.ToString();
                    }
                }
```

I'm getting the following error: 
Additional information: Type 'DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

I'm not sure how to get around this problem, as don't have access to high charts class to make any changes, searching the web it also seems the problem could be that Highcharts class does not have a constructor that takes zero parameters but again i can't add this in myself.

Any help on getting around this issue would be great thanks.l

Comment: Copy the necessary fields of `Highcharts` class to a custom object and use it to serialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like L.B pointed out, putting the data properties of my Highcharts dictionary into a separate object and then storing that within my model done the trick for me.

Then after de-serialization I instantiated my highcharts object with those same properties from within my model and sent it to the view.

Thanks L.B